# texture mapping

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, texture-mapping

I'm trying to apply texture to a sprite using opengl as follows:

```
int[] textures=new int[1];
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
Bitmap bitmap=null;
try {
   bitmap=  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(contxt.getAssets().open("gfx/garf.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0, bitmap, 0);
bitmap.recycle();
```

.....

I'm using andEngine framework in android and using onManagedDraw method of Sprite to do this.

Can anyone help in this direction?

Comment: You should post the drawing code also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need texImage2D(**GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D**, 0, bitmap, 0);

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing that your problem is that the texture doesn't show up :)

This is wrong:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Should be:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Comment: I tried using GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0), but still the texture doesn't show up.